# One time Internet Connection Check swift

Tags: swift, internet-connection

I need to check the internet connection of a user for one time.

I thought of something like `Device.isConnectedToTheInternet` but I didn't find something similar...
Every solution that if found was like an internet monitor over time, but that's not exactly what I need.

Someone ideas?
Thanks, Boothosh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rob Napier mentioned, it looks like the only thing readily available is the NWPathMonitor, which you can use to check the 'connectivity' to a certain location, like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), or something else that would be relatively trustworthy to be available 24/7, or just the URL you are about to try and use. Here is a short [HackingWithSwift tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/networking/how-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-nwpathmonitor) for NWPathMonitor.

I know this isn't exactly your current situation, but in my projects (and a lot of peoples projects) using an API like [AlamoFire](http://alamofire.org/) is pretty common, and has a ton of usefulness for creating GET/PUT/POST/DELETE requests and of course, has a NetworkReachabilityManager which can be used to make a convenient global function for a simple true/false result for 'isConnectedToInternet' like this:

```
 /*
 Connectivity
 Struct
 Utilizes AlamoFire to check for network availability.
 isConnectedToInternet should return true in all cases the phone has access (Cellular, No cellular + wifi, Cellular + wifi, wifi)
*/
struct Connectivity {
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkReachabilityManager()!
    static var isConnectedToInternet:Bool {
        let connected = self.sharedInstance.isReachable
        return connected
    }
}//end Connectivity
```

Answer (score 0):

See [NWPathMonitor().currentPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpathmonitor/2998732-currentpath). It will tell you the current path. This is only occasionally useful, since "connected to the internet" is not a meaningful condition. There is not concrete definition of "the internet." But you can use the NWPath to answer some questions you probably are looking for. The fact that there is an NSPath available does not mean that you can actually connect to something on "the internet." The *only* way to know that is to send a packet and get a packet back. So if your real question is "can I connect to a specific host," then you're going to need to send packets to that host (and that still won't prove that you can send packets to the host in the future).

All that said, there is a little UI-level usefulness to asking "if I tried to connect, would it certainly fail?" And `currentPath` can help you answer that. It just can't tell you if it would succeed.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what im looking for. How would you use it? I tried the following code:

if NWPathMonitor().currentPath.status == .unsatisfied {
            print("No connection")
        }

but even with a nice internet connection it prints "No connection"...

Comment: You may need to wait for it to update (likely setting it up in AppDelegate). It may not be ready as soon as its created. (I always use pathUpdateHandler, and only occasionally check `current`.)

Comment: But that was what I was looking for... I need something that checks the internet connection and do depending on the result different things, on a button tap :(

Comment: See jcodes's answer (which is good), but almost likely for anything reliable, you'll need some level of async, and even then, you should not assume it's reliable. The *only* way to know whether a network connection will be successful is to try it.